# How to retrieve a specific fields from two mondoDb joined collections using Morphia?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I join two collections using aggregate $lookup.

```
"users"

{    
"_id" : ObjectId("5984f8c454b1fd6926c324fd"),
    "email" : "administrator@hotmail.com",
    "userId" : "uid",
    "userName" : "admin"
}
"userinfo"

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d82812b63f1c31cf906003"),
    "userId" : "uid",
    "phone" : "000000000"
}
```

I use @Reference(idOnly = true) in my "users" entity class to reference the second collection. I want to retrieve only specific fields like: "email", "userId", "phone".

```
Query<Users> query =  usersDAO.createQuery()
                .retrievedFields(true,"email", "userId", "phone")
```

It gives me a run-time error not recognizing the "phone" filed, since it comes from referenced collection "userinfo". I tried specifying "userinfo.phone", etc. with no luck. It works fine when the "phone" field gets eliminated from the query.
What would be a proper way to achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per $lookup query, userinfo will be added to users document with the name you mentioned for "as" field in the lookup query.

So you should use phone like lookup_as.phone

**If the lookup query is as below**

```
{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "userinfo",
        "localField": "userId",
        "foreignField": "userId",
        "as": "uinfo"
    }
}
```

**So in this case you should use**

```
    Query query =  usersDAO.createQuery() .retrievedFields(true,"email", "userId", "uinfo.phone")
```

Comment: Since I'm not explicitly specifying MongoDB lookup query (Morphia does create some query under the hood) the  "uinfo" alias doesn't seem to become available through Morphia , so  the "uinfo.phone" raises an exception.

Comment: Let me to clarify my question. I need to join two MondoDB collections using Morphia and retrieve a set of specific fields.

Comment: Is there any equivalent with new Morphia project() function? in Morphia 1.3.2? to get multiple fields at same line